# Segmentation fault (Core dumped) on importing torch with python3.5 in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, segmentation-fault, pytorch, coredump

I have installed `torch=0.4.1` without `cuda` in a `virtualenv`. I am using `python3.5` on ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I `import torch` in an interactive python shell, it quits the python program by showing `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. 
[image: Error on importing torch]

While, surprisingly I had earlier initialized a `jupyter notebook` and tried importing torch there and it was running fine. Can someone please help? I could not find a solution on official `PyTorch github' discussions.
[image: Jupyter notebook torch import working fine]

Comment: are your jupyter notebook and virtualenv using the same site-packages and the same interppreter?

Comment: I could not check the path of module imported in interactive shell, since it shows seg fault the moment I `import torch`. However, I imported some other package and it shows that both the site-packages and path are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the solution was given on [GitHub](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/926#issuecomment-284258385):

```
import cv2        # first import cv2
import torch
```